# How should I simulate 1000 concurrent users as real?

Tags: testing, concurrency, jmeter

I need to do a load testing for a web service. It requires at least 1000 concurrent users.

I know some testing tools (e.g JMeter) could simulate a bunch of concurrent users with multiple-threads. But those users are not really concurrent.

If I run the JMeter program in a machine with only 2 CPU cores, there is only 2 concurrent users active in a time, even though there are 1000 multiple threads generated with the testing tool.

Is there any way to create real concurrent users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the point of view of the web service, those users *are* concurrent. A CPU with two cores can easily swap between 1000 threads; most of the time, the thread will be waiting for network I/O, so it's very similar to how it would work if you actually had 1000 cores.

So JMeter should be fine. It's possible that if the test thread has to do a load of CPU-intensive work, then that might bias the results. But usually, the test threads are just waiting for a response.

Comment: +1 for being realistic. If you need one user per CPU then you would need 1000 CPUs, which might be 'real' but is not realistic.

Answer (score 3):

You can try *nix tool [Siege](http://www.joedog.org) after reading [FAQ about concurrent users](http://www.joedog.org/siege-faq/#a16).

Comment: What's the advantage of Siege compared with JMeter?

Comment: Siege works from the command prompt, it's quite easy to use out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can look also onto [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/), which has [SOAP support using the HTTP mode](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual.html), as well.